# How to import own self created windows keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Is it possible to import an own Windows keyboard layout or I need to generate it new?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to choose one of the available layouts:

Go to System Settings and choose Keyboard Layout:

[image]

Then you can click at "+" to add a preconfigured layout:

[image]

If none is exactly what you need, you can made some changes with [Xmodmap](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html).